# How to compute $\mathbb{E}[\|\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k\in\cal{K}}\bf{X}_k-\bf{X}\|^2]$?

Tags: probability, random-variable, stochastic-processes

Assume vector $\bf{X}_k\in\mathbb{R}^N$, for all $k\in\cal{K}=\{1,2,\cdots,K\}$ are $K$ i.i.d. random variables. If each $\bf{X}_k$ is an unbiased estimator of parameter $\bf X$, then how to compute the following expression? Assume that $\mathbb{E}[\|\bf{X}_k\|]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\|\bf{X}_k\|^2]$ are known in advance.

$$\mathbb{E}[\|\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k\in\cal{K}}\bf{X}_k-\bf{X}\|^2]$$

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244301/is-there-a-corresponding-bias-variance-decomposition-of-mse-for-vectors

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3740140/321264