# What's the MSE of $\hat{Y}$ in ordinary least squares using bias-variance decomposition?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, mse

Suppose I have the following model: $$Y = \mu + \epsilon = X\beta + \epsilon,$$ where $Y$ is $n \times 1$, $X$ is $n \times p$, $\beta$ is $p \times 1$, and $\epsilon$ is $n \times 1$. I assume that $\epsilon$ are independent with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2I$.

In OLS, the fitted values are $\hat{Y} = HY$, where $H = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is the $N \times N$ hat matrix. I want to find the MSE of $\hat{Y}$.

By the bias-variance decomposition, I know that

\begin{align*}
MSE(\hat{Y}) &= bias^2(\hat{Y}) + var(\hat{Y})\\
&= (E[HY] - \mu)^T(E[HY] - \mu) + var(HY)\\
&= (H\mu - \mu)^T(H\mu - \mu) + \sigma^2H\\
&= 0 + \sigma^2H
\end{align*}

I'm confused by the dimension in the last step. The $bias^2$ term is a scalar. However, $var(\hat{Y})$ is an $N \times N$ matrix. How can one add a scalar to an $N \times N$ matrix where $N \neq 1$?

Comment: Here is a good blog to explain differences, including in a machine learning context at https://www.bmc.com/blogs/mean-squared-error-r2-and-variance-in-regression-analysis/ .

Comment: On the additive bias term, a matrix can have all its elements equal to zero.

Comment: @AJKOER so are you implying that $(H\mu - \mu)^T(H\mu - \mu)$ is a matrix of all 0's?

Comment: Your dimensions don't work out, because on the second line of your MSE calculation the dimensions suddenly change.

Comment: @whuber, yes, it seems like starting from the second line the dimensions already do not match. How would you suggest I write the starting equation? or the second line to get the dimensions right from the get go

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "MSE."  The usual meanings are scalar in nature, but you seem to want it to be an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: @whuber I am familiar with the MSE decomposition in the scalar case. I just wanted to write things out in matrix notation. But even then I think the final MSE should still be a scalar, not a matrix. Is there a way to write the MSE using matrix notation of $Y$, and $X$, to get a scalar at the end, I may need to take the trace of something to get a scalar?...

Comment: Isn't the error vector $e = \hat Y - X\beta$?  In that case the mean square error is $|e|^2/n$ or, if you prefer, $e^\prime e/n.$

Comment: @whuber that makes sense. do you think it's possible to do a bias-variance decomposition of the MSE in this case?

Comment: Sure, because the bias of the MSE is well-known and easy to compute.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/244301/119261

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*More explanation in the edit below*

I think the confusion arises because of the two different meanings of the MSE:

1. [A value calculated from a sample of fitted values or predictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Predictor); this is usually what we mean when we write $\operatorname{MSE}(\hat{Y})$ in the context of OLS, since $\hat{Y}$ is the vector of fitted values.
2. [A value calculated from an estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Estimator). It is this meaning where we have the variance–bias decomposition. We use this meaning of the MSE in the context of OLS too, but usually for the MSE of $\hat{\beta}$, where $\hat{\beta}$ is [an estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator) of the parameter $\beta$. By the [Gauss–Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem) we know that $\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{\beta}) = 0$ and thus $\operatorname{MSE}(\hat{\beta}) = \operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta})$ by the variance–bias decomposition if we take $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$.

However, we can view $\hat{Y}$ as an estimator of $X\beta$ and thus consider $\operatorname{MSE}(\hat{Y})$ in the second sense. This is really just a rephrasing of the usual OLS estimator of $\beta$: In the normal setup we estimate the parameter $\beta$ given $X$ and $Y$, while in this new setup we estimate the parameter $X\beta$ given $X$ and $Y$. Alas the notation is now confusing, since the notation $\hat{Y}$ suggests that we are estimating $Y$ (a random variable), which we are *not* doing.

To simplify the formalism, we will use the notation of the OP and define $\mu = X\beta$. **Don't confuse this with a mean!**

We also have to clarify some definitions, since we are now dealing with a vector-valued estimator. First the variance (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99642/802868) for some explanation):

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Var}(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]\right)\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]\right)^T\right]
\end{equation*}

The definition of the bias doesn't change from the 1-dimensional case:

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu
\end{equation*}

However, we do have to find a vector-valued equivalent of the 1-dimensional expression $\operatorname{Bias}_\mu(\hat{Y})^2$, since this appears in the variance–bias decomposition. In the same vein as the vector-valued variance, this equivalent expression is the following:

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})^T
\end{equation*}

Note that $\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})$ is a fixed vector, so if the expression $\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu$ appears within the scope of an expected-value operator, we can take it out as a constant. [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123320/mse-decomposition-to-variance-and-bias-squared) is about this fact, albeit for the 1-dimensional case.

And finally the MSE itself:

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{MSE}(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{E} \left [\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^T \right]
\end{equation*}

So, with all this in hand, we can now prove the variance–bias decomposition of the MSE for a vector-valued estimator, which is really just a rephrasing of [the usual proof for the 1-dimensional case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Proof_of_variance_and_bias_relationship):

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{MSE}(\hat{Y}) &= \operatorname{E} \left [\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^T \right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]+\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu\right)\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]+\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu\right)^T\right]\\ 
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]\right)+\left(\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu\right)\right)\left(\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]\right)^T+\left(\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu\right)^T\right)\right]\\ 
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]\right)\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]\right)^T +\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}] \right ) \left (\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)^T\right. \\
&\hphantom{xxxxxxxxxx} + \left.\left(\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}] \right)^T +\left( \operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)\left( \operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)^T\right] \\ 
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]\right)\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]\right)^T\right]
+ \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}] \right ) \left (\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)^T\right] \\
&\hphantom{xxxxxxxxxx} + \operatorname{E}\left[\left (\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}] \right)^T\right] + \operatorname{E}\left[\left( \operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)\left( \operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)^T\right] \\ 
&=\operatorname{Var}(\hat{Y}) + \operatorname{E}\left[\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}] \right]\left(\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)^T \\
&\hphantom{xxxxxxxxxx} +
\left (\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)\operatorname{E}\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}] \right)^T\right]+ \left( \operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)\left( \operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)^T \hphantom{xx} (*)\\ 
&=\operatorname{Var}(\hat{Y}) + \left(\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}] \right)\left(\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)^T \\
& \hphantom{xxxxxxxxxx}+
\left (\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)\left(\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}] \right)^T + \operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})^T \\ 
&=\operatorname{Var}(\hat{Y}) + 0\left(\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)^T +
\left (\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \right)0^T + \operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})^T \\ 
&= \operatorname{Var}(\hat{Y}) + \operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})^T
\end{align*}

Let's now actually calculate the bias and the variance of the estimator $\hat{Y}$:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y}) &= \operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}-\mu] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY-X\beta\right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[X\left((X^TX)^{-1}X^TY-\beta\right)\right] \\
&= X\operatorname{E}\left[(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY-\beta\right] \\
&= X\operatorname{E}[\hat{\beta}-\beta] \\
&= X0 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

The equality $\operatorname{E}[\hat{\beta}-\beta]=0$ is a consequence of the [Gauss–Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem). Note that $\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})=0$ implies that $\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]=\mu$ by simple rearrangement.

We now calculate the variance:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(\hat{Y}) &= \operatorname{E}\left[(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}])(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}])^T\right]\\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[(\hat{Y}-\mu)(\hat{Y}-\mu)^T\right]\\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[(X\hat{\beta}-X\beta)(X\hat{\beta}-X\beta)^T\right]\\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[X(\hat{\beta}-\beta)(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^TX^T\right]\\
&= X\operatorname{E}\left[(\hat{\beta}-\beta)(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^T\right]X^T\\
&= X\operatorname{E}\left[(\hat{\beta}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{\beta}])(\hat{\beta}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{\beta}])^T\right]X^T \hphantom{xx} (\text{by the Gauss–Markow theorem})\\
&= X\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta})X^T\\
&= X(\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}X^T) \hphantom{xx} (**)\\
&= X(\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)\\
&= \sigma^2X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\\
&= \sigma^2H
\end{align*}

We prove the step marked $(**)$, namely that $\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$:

\begin{align*}
\hat{\beta} - \beta &= (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY - \beta \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta + \epsilon) - \beta \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^TX\beta + (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon - \beta \\
&= \beta + (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon - \beta \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon
\end{align*}

Thus:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta}) &=\operatorname{E}\left[(\hat{\beta}-\beta)(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^T\right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon((X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon)^T\right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon\epsilon^TX(X^TX)^{-T}\right] \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\operatorname{E}\left[\epsilon\epsilon^T\right]X(X^TX)^{-T} \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\operatorname{E}\left[(\epsilon-0)(\epsilon-0)^T\right]X(X^TX)^{-T} \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\operatorname{E}\left[(\epsilon-\operatorname{E}[\epsilon])(\epsilon-\operatorname{E}[\epsilon])^T\right]X(X^TX)^{-T} \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon)X(X^TX)^{-T} \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T(\sigma^2I)X(X^TX)^{-T} \hphantom{xx} (\text{since the errors are uncorrelated with each other})\\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T(\sigma^2I)X(X^TX)^{-T} \\
&= \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}X^TX(X^TX)^{-T} \\
&= \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-T} \\
&= \sigma^2((X^TX)^T)^{-1} \\
&= \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1} \\
\end{align*}

So, putting it all together:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{MSE}(\hat{Y}) &= \operatorname{Var}(\hat{Y}) + \operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})^T \\
&= \sigma^2H + 00^T \\
&= \sigma^2H
\end{align*}

This is the answer that the OP calculated. :)

---

**EDIT**

The OP asked in the comments why we define

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{MSE}(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{E} \left [\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^T \right]
\end{equation*}

and not

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{MSE}(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{E} \left[\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^T\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right) \right].
\end{equation*}

This is a good question; indeed, it's the crux of the OP's original question and I didn't address it properly. I will attempt to redress this oversight.

In the 1-dimensional case, the meaning of the definition

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{MSE}(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^2\right]
\end{equation*}

is unambiguous. But if $\hat{Y}-\mu$ is a vector, then we have to decide how to interpret the expression $\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^2$. We have two options:

1. $\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^2 = \left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^T\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)$
2. $\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^2 = \left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^T$

In my original answer I went with the second option (based on arguments given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99642/802868)). But what about the first option? Well, we still have the variance–bias decomposition! Let's show that. We start by defining all the relevant terms; I mark them with a superscript asterisk * in order to distinguish them from the definitions given in my original answer, but please note that this is **not** standard notation:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{MSE}^*(\hat{Y}) &= \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^T\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right) \right] \\
\operatorname{Var}^*(\hat{Y}) &= \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]\right)^T\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]\right)\right] \\
\operatorname{Bias}^*(\hat{Y}) &= \operatorname{E}[\hat{Y}]-\mu \left(= \operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y}) \right)\\
\operatorname{Bias}^*(\hat{Y})^2 &= \operatorname{Bias}^*(\hat{Y})^T\operatorname{Bias}^*(\hat{Y})
\end{align*}

(Note that we could multiply by the constant factor $\frac{1}{n}$, i.e. define

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{MSE}^*(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{E}\left[\tfrac{1}{n}\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^T\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right) \right].
\end{equation*}

It doesn't really matter whether we include this constant factor, since it has no effect on the expected-value operator.)

With these definitions, the MSE still decomposes into the sum of the variance and the square of the bias:

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{MSE}^*(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{Var}^*(\hat{Y}) + \operatorname{Bias}^*(\hat{Y})^2
\end{equation*}

The proof is all but identical to the one given above: One just has to move a few superscript $T$s around.

What the OP did in their original calculation was to mix up the different definitions when they applied the variance–bias decomposition: They used $\operatorname{Var}^*(\hat{Y})$ but $\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{Y})^T$. This is why the dimensions didn't match.

Comment: Why is the MSE defined as $\operatorname{MSE}_\mu(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{E}_\mu \left [\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^T \right]$ and not $\operatorname{MSE}_\mu(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{E}_\mu \left [\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)^T\left(\hat{Y}-\mu\right)\right]$ instead?

Comment: @Adrian A good question. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! One last question: Is $\operatorname{Var}^*_\mu(\hat{Y}) = \operatorname{E}_\mu\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}_\mu[\hat{Y}]\right)^T\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}_\mu[\hat{Y}]\right)\right]$ equivalent to $trace\left(\operatorname{E}_\mu\left[\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}_\mu[\hat{Y}]\right)\left(\hat{Y}-\operatorname{E}_\mu[\hat{Y}]\right)^T\right]\right)$? Typically when I think of variance (or covariance) of a vector like $\hat{Y}$ I think it's a matrix, thus the outerproduct.

Comment: Yes. This is a consequence of the additivity of the expected-value operator and the [general fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Trace_of_a_product) that $\operatorname{tr}(vv^T) = v^Tv$ for any vector $v$.